# Trouble Compiling App.Js code using use Effect and use State hooks in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to run a web page using useState for Game State and setting game state on a website rendered using React. There are problems compiling with three variables undefined. (Set_GAME_State, SNIPPETS and Snippet Index).

This is based on Daniel Katz's tutorial on using Hooks (useEffect and use State) from the latest version of react: [Link] (https://medium.com/@dtkatz/react-hooks-tutorial-learn-by-building-b90ec4db2b8e)

I tried naming the constant and setting the variable before the hooks but to no avail.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const [snippet, setSnippet]= useState('');
const [userText, setUserText] = useState('');
const [gameState, setGameState] = useState(INITIAL_Game_State);

setSnippet(SNIPPETS[snippetIndex]);
setGameState({...gameState, startTime: new Date().getTime() });

useEffect (() => {
  if (gameState.victory) document.title = 'Victory!';
});
....
  const chooseSnippet = snippetIndex => () => {
    console.log('setSnippet', snippetIndex);
    setSnippet(SNIPPETS[snippetIndex]);
  }; 
  const updateUserText = event => {
      setUserText (event.target.value);

    if (event.target.value === snippet) {
      setGameState({
      ...gameState,
      victory: true,
      endTime: new Date().getTime() -gameState.startTime
      });
    }
      console.log('current userText', userText);
    }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2> Type Race</h2>
      <hr />
      <h3> Snippet </h3>
      {snippet}
      <h4> {gameState.victory ? `Done!  Time: ${gameState.endTime}ms` : null}</h4>
     <input value={userText} onChange={updateUserText} />
     <hr />
     {
       SNIPPETS.map((SNIPPET, index) => (
         <button onClick={chooseSnippet(index)} key={index}>
         {SNIPPET.substring(0,10)}...
         </button>
       ))
     }
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

This is the App Css file

```
css
.App {
  text-align: center;
}

.App-logo {
  animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear;
  height: 40vmin;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.App-header {
  background-color: #282c34;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
  color: white;
}

.App-link {
  color: #61dafb;
}

@keyframes App-logo-spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

This is the initial game state javascript file.

```
const INITIAL_GAME_STATE = { victory: false, startTime: null, endTime: null};
const [snippet, setSnippet]= useState('');
const [userText, setUserText] = useState('');
const [gameState, setGameState] = useState(INITIAL_GAME_STATE);

setSnippet(SNIPPETS[snippetIndex]);
setGameState({...gameState, startTime: new Date().getTime() });
```

Errors Shown: 
./src/App.js
  Line 5:  'INITIAL_Game_State' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 7:  'SNIPPETS' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 7:  'snippetIndex' is not defined        no-undef

It should show the website with the game state and other text as written in the javascript code.

Comment: The error  is telling you exactly whats wrong those variables arent defined. Can you post your entire app as is it seems you are missing a few things

Comment: i have added the components! @iqbal125

Answer (score 0):

In the linked article both SNIPPETS and INTIIAL_Game_State are defined prior to the hooks.

From the article:

```
const INITIAL_GAME_STATE = { victory: false, startTime: null, endTime: null };
const [snippet, setSnippet] = useState('');
const [userText, setUserText] = useState('');
const [gameState, setGameState] = useState(INITIAL_GAME_STATE);
```

and for snippets:

```
const SNIPPETS = [
  'Bears, beets, battlestar galactica',
  "What's Forrest Gump's password? 1Forrest1",
  'Where do programmers like to hangout? The Foo Bar'
];
const [snippet, setSnippet] = useState('');
const [userText, setUserText] = useState('');
```

Should just be a matter of either including those declarations prior to using them. It looks like they're removed in your example. Just include both above where you use the hooks and you should be set.

His full app.js [here](https://github.com/15Dkatz/typerace-hooks/blob/master/src/App.js)

Comment: Happy to help! :) Hooks are sweet!